# What is the MonoDevelop default font?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm wondering what it is - I particularly like how they render the lowercase "l" and crossed zero - imho, they look better than Consolas / Inconsolata.

I've tried both googling for it as well as looking for it in Start > Control Panel > Fonts to no avail.

If Stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask this kind of question - please direct me to a more appropriate stack/forum and I'll move it there.

Screenshot:

[image: MonoDevelop screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font looks a lot like DejaVu Sans Mono:

http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page

They in particular have the 0 and l marked like you suggest. There is an Ubuntu font which does the same and which has the ubuntu-specific 'u' character.

As for Inconsolata, it is a magnificent font, but it does require high PPI in order to work well. More than what most screens provide. You need at least 200 for it to look good.

Comment: Yes, it is DejaVu Sans Mono.  It's the default Monospace font in GNOME on Debian, too.

Comment: excellent. I'll have this answer accepted as soon as the cooldown expires. ty for your tip on insonsolata.